# Раcпарсить XML

Tags: xml, php, синтаксический-анализ

Здравствуйте, есть XML следующего вида (тут маленький кусок):

```
<init can_send_fuel='1' day='735440' user_agent=''><user default_car='59363292' tank='0' races_lost='0' gold='0' money='800' races_won='0' fuel_ts='1406212478' fuel_base='100' money_spent='3700'
```

Нужно получить значение элемента default_car.
Как туда добраться можно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле нужен кусок по больше, чтобы видеть структуру. А вообще примерно вот:

```
<?php
$xmlstr = "<init can_send_fuel='1' day='735440' user_agent=''><user default_car='59363292' tank='0' races_lost='0' gold='0' money='800' races_won='0' fuel_ts='1406212478' fuel_base='100' money_spent='3700'/></init>";
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);
echo $xml->user[0]->attributes()->default_car; /* 59363292 */
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо, что отозвались 
Задачку уже решил, при том намного проще:
$out = file_get_contents("УРЛ ДО XML");
list($a, $b) = explode("default_car='", $out, 2);
$default_car = intval($b);